# How to solve postman Get picture verification code garbled

Tags: postman

[I want to get the result of image verification code using postman, but the obtained result is garbled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1CRQ.png)

Comment: please post the image directly to SO. Also please take some time to read the stack overflow question asking guidelines

Comment: I have posted the picture, here is the link to my picture：https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1CRQ.png

Comment: Great, as for your question, it is very hard to answer with only this much information. Try checking the response contenttype for your api. Maybe you set a wrong response type that is confusing postman

Comment: Response type is captcha image

Answer (score 1):

in your postman click the pointer next to send button you will get option to send and download . which will download your image and allow you to save.